# Display message dialog if JTextField does not contain data

Tags: java, exception, jtextfield

I am writing a BMI calculator application. Currently an error happens which causes the program to stop working if I do not enter data into one field. For instance, there are two JTextFIelds for 'height', one being feet and the other inches. If I just input '6' into the feet JTextField and enter nothing into inches JTextField, then enter my weight in the weight JTextField and click on calculate, it does not work.

What I want to do is display a message dialog saying "Please make sure all fields are filled in" if one field does not contain data.

Below is the ActionHandler code that is added to my 'Calculate' button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    double heightFT = ((Double.parseDouble(heightFt_TF.getText()));
    double heightIn = (Double.parseDouble(heightIn_TF.getText()));
    double weight = (Double.parseDouble(weight_TF.getText()));
    double totalHeight = (heightFT*12) + heightIn;              
            
    BMI = (weight / (totalHeight*totalHeight)) * 703;
    String s = BMI+"";
    s = s.substring(0,4);
    BMI_TF.setText(s);                              
}
```

---

#### Solved

I have now fixed the problem. What I did was add 'throws NumberFormatException' in the method and did a try catch. In the try code block I wrote the code I want to execute if all data fields are entered. In the catch clause I wrote code that uses the NumberFormatException and simply displays the message dialog with the error message. Now, if one field is not entered, the message dialog appears!

Comment: The JTextfields which you refer to should be validated (Not Empty, Not null, Not a Number)

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your JTextField objects contain text.
E.g:

```
if (heightFt_TF.getText() == null || heightIn_TF.getText() == null || weight_TF.getText() == null) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure all fields are filled in");
}
```

Of course you also have to make sure, that the content of the textfields really contains a number.

Comment: Matthias, I tried this but get the following error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"             java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Answer (score 0):

Download Apache Commons Lang library and use `StringUtils.isBlank(myTextField.getText());` to validate your fields.

```
public boolean validateFields() {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(heightFt_TF.getText()) {
        // show message
        return false;
    }

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(weight_TF.getText()) {
        // show message
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Only run your calculation if validateFields() returns true.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean validate(JTextField field) {

  boolean result = field.getText() != null;
  if (result) {
    try {
      Double.parseDouble(field.getText()));
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      result = false
    } 
  }
  return result;                    
}
```